# How to call a function from another file into main function in c?

Tags: c, qt

I am using qt and created a c project. I have created two files one header file and source file. I have declare a function into header file. So that I can call it from main function. But when I compile and run, I got "undefined reference to " error. How to solve this issue ? I am using qt 5.5 ide.

My Code:

header file
chapter_1.h

```
#ifndef CHAPTER_1_H
#define CHAPTER_1_H

//include all header files
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

/* function declaration */
int sum(int x, int y);

#endif // CHAPTER_1_H
```

source file

```
//include header files

#include "chapter_1.h"

int sum(int x, int y)
{
    int result = x+y;

    return result;
}
```

main file:

```
#include "chapter_1.h" 

int main()
{
    sum(23, 23);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Undefined reference to what? To `sum()`?

Comment: Also, you don't need includes for `stdio.h`, `stdlib.h` and `conio.h`. You are not using these libraries anyway.

Comment: When you do need headers included for a certain source file, it's usually preferred to include them just in the files that need them rather than sticking them all in another header (especially for standard headers).

Comment: only `#include` a header file inside a header file if that header file actually uses something within the `#included` header file.  I.E. place the #include statements in the source file

Answer (score 6):

It's not a compiler error. It's a linker error.  You just need to include **both** source files (main.cpp and chapter1.cpp) into your project.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. The problem was, file created as .cpp. Now I have changed it into .c and not it worked. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

You must tell the `qmake` which are the source files that you want to use to generate program. There is a couple of variables defined in project file ( `*.pro`) which are responsible for this and other information. `SOURCES` defines the source files to use, `HEADERS` - you guessed, the headers.

```
HEADERS = chapter_1.h
SOURCES = main.cpp chapter_1.cpp
```